# How to stop downloading page when posting data with curl command?

Tags: curl, post, command-line, http-post

I would not like to download the page after posting data in such situation—

```
curl \
     -L -s --compressed \
     -w '%{url_effective}' \
    --cookie "$cookieFile" \
    --cookie-jar "$cookieFile" \
    --form localid=$pnum --form language=$lan --form "codeupl=@$path" \
    'https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=25&page=save_submission'
```

This generates a lot of text in stdout, the whole download page.

Using -I (--head option) is not working here. What will be the solution for this? I just want to post data, not download anything.

Comment: redirect the output to /dev/null and leave it at that?

Comment: I do not want to download the page, so that, the command executes at the fastest time. Redirecting to /dev/null will be same, downloading but not showing.